# Scraping with Beautiful Soup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have stumbled across this excellent [post](http://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/easy-web-scraping-with-python) on scraping using Beautiful Soup and I decided to take on the task of scraping some data off the internet to try.

I be using the flight data from [Flight Radar 24](http://www.flightradar24.com/data/flights/tigerair-tgw/) and using what was described in the blog post to try automating scraping through the pages for flight data.

```
import requests
import bs4

root_url = 'http://www.flightradar24.com'
index_url = root_url + '/data/flights/tigerair-tgw/'


def get_flight_id_urls():
     response = requests.get(index_url)
     soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(response.text)
     return [a.attrs.get('href') for a in soup.select('div.list-group a[href^=/data]')]


flight_id_urls = get_flight_id_urls()
for flight_id_url in flight_id_urls:
    temp_url = root_url + flight_id_url
    response = requests.get(temp_url)
    soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(response.text)

try:
    table = soup.find('table')
    rows = table.find_all('tr')
    for row in rows:
        flight_data = {}
        flight_data['title'] = soup.select('div#cntPagePreTitle h1')[0].get_text()
        flight_data['tr'] = row #error here
        print (flight_data)

except AttributeError as e:
    raise ValueError("No valid table found")
```

sample of a [flight data page](http://www.flightradar24.com/data/flights/tr2424/)

I stumbled till the table and then realized I don't know how to transverse down the table attributes to get the data that was embedded in each column.

Any kind soul have any clues, even tutorials to intro so that I can read up on how to extract the data.

P.S: credits to Miguel Grinberg for the excellent tutorial

Added

```
try:
table = soup.find('table')
rows = table.find_all('tr')
heads = [i.text.strip() for i in table.select('thead th')]
for tr in table.select('tbody tr'):
    flight_data = {}
    flight_data['title'] = soup.select('div#cntPagePreTitle h1')[0].get_text()
    flight_data['From'] = tr.select('td.From') 
    flight_data['To'] = tr.select('td.To')

    print (flight_data)

except AttributeError as e:
     raise ValueError("No valid table found")
```

I changed the last part of my code to form a data object but I can't seem to get the data.

**The final edit:**

```
import requests
import bs4

root_url = 'http://www.flightradar24.com'
index_url = root_url + '/data/flights/tigerair-tgw/'


def get_flight_id_urls():
     response = requests.get(index_url)
     soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(response.text)
     return [a.attrs.get('href') for a in soup.select('div.list-group a[href^=/data]')]


flight_id_urls = get_flight_id_urls()
for flight_id_url in flight_id_urls:
    temp_url = root_url + flight_id_url
    response = requests.get(temp_url)
    soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(response.text)

try:
    table = soup.find('table')
    rows = table.find_all('tr')
    for row in rows:
        flight_data = {}
        flight_data['flight_number'] = tr['data-flight-number']
        flight_data['from'] = tr['data-name-from']
        print (flight_data)

except AttributeError as e:
    raise ValueError("No valid table found")
```

P.S.S: All thanks to @amow for his great help :D

Comment: `I don't know how to transverse down the table attributes to get the data that was embedded in each column.` just post the source code here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Start with `table` as your table in html.

```
heads = [i.text.strip() for i in table.select('thead th')]
for tr in table.select('tbody tr'):
    datas = [i.text.strip() for i in tr.select('td')]
    print dict(zip(heads, datas))
```

**Output**

```
{   
    u'STD': u'06:30',   
    u'Status': u'Scheduled',   
    u'ATD': u'-',  
    u'From': u'Singapore  (SIN)',  
    u'STA': u'07:55',  
    u'\xa0': u'', #This is the last column and have no meaning  
    u'To': u'Penang  (PEN)',  
    u'Aircraft': u'-',  
    u'Date': u'2015-04-19'
}
```

If you want to get the data in the tr tag. Just use

```
tr['data-data'] tr['data-flight-number']
```

and so on.

Comment: thanks for the prompt reply, I can see that you are stripping the data from each column into an array, is it possible to get each specify column, I try  `flight_data['From'] = tr.select('td.From')` but it gives me nothing.

Comment: @jonleech Of course you can, but the `select` function only support `css` syntax.So if you want to get the `from location`, you can use `tr.select('td')[1]`.Because there is no specific identifier of the `location td`,you can only use the list index , thats denpends on the index of the `location` column in the table.Btw, the `from location` also can be found as an attribute of `tr`, just use `tr['data-name-from']`

Comment: @jonleech The keys of output json come from the table header, not from the column td.So I guess when you use the `tr.select('td.From')`, you mistake the `From` as the attr of `td`.That's not true.You can use chrome's `inspect element` in right click menu to find out how to locate each element in a html doc.

Comment: alright thanks alot. will go tinker with the code. your help is much appreciated :D

Comment: yea I made the mistake that thinking the title of the header can be translated in to an attribute name, I was thinking is python that powerful.. sorry my mistake :D

Comment: I will like to ask if it's possible to check if the key for the in `tr['data-flight-number']` exists as there are some empty tables and when I try to scrap flight data it hits an error..

Comment: I tried `if tr['data-flight-number'] is None:` but the key doesn't exists and this hits the KeyError straight away ... thanks